# Style last element on every printed page differently

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries, css-paged-media

I have a list of elements (arbitrary length). However, when user is printing it, I want to change the style of the last element on every page.

So far I tried using `@page {.el:last-child...}` but that does nothing. and using simply `el:last-child` only applies styling to the last child on the last page.

Any help is appreciated.

I have the following HTML:

```css
.el {
  width: 500px;
  height:250px;
  background:#ccc;
  margin:10px;
}
@page {
  .el:last-child {
    font-weight:bold;
  }
}
@media print {
  .el {display:block;}
}
```

```html
    <div>
     <div class="el"> element </div>
     <div class="el"> element </div>
     <div class="el"> element </div>
     <div class="el"> element </div>
     <div class="el"> element </div>
     <div class="el"> element </div>
     <div class="el"> element </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no selector for this AFAIK. "pages" are artifical constructs and not DOM elements and so cannot be used by CSS.

Answer (score 2):

As per [MDN @page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page),

> You can't change all CSS properties with @page. You can only change
>   the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document.
>   Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to your container div and use `last-child` with that.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deftehsafc/ac5LjLxq/)

Comment: that applies only to the last-child on the last page as I mentioned in my post